# What is the role of the package-lock.json?

Tags: npm

npm@5 has been published, it has a new feature **`package-lock.json`** file (after `npm install`) which confuses me. I want to know, what is the effect of this file?

Comment: package-lock. json to keep track of exact dependency trees at any given time. It will ensure that all clients that download your project and attempt to install dependencies will get the exact same dependency tree.

Answer (score 515, accepted):

It stores an **exact, versioned dependency tree** rather than using starred versioning like `package.json` itself (e.g. 1.0.*). This means you can guarantee the dependencies for other developers or prod releases, etc. It also has a mechanism to lock (hence the name `package-lock`) the tree but generally will regenerate if `package.json` changes.

From [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json):

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.
>
> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and serves various purposes:
>
> Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies.
>
> Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
>
> To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source control diffs.
>
> And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages."

### Edit

To answer jrahhali's question below about just using the `package.json` with exact version numbers. Bear in mind that your `package.json` contains only your direct dependencies, not the dependencies of your dependencies (sometimes called nested or transitive dependencies). This means with the standard `package.json` you can't control the versions of those nested dependencies, referencing them directly or as peer dependencies won't help as you also don't control the version tolerance that your direct dependencies define for these nested dependencies.

Even if you lock down the versions of your direct dependencies you cannot 100% guarantee that your full dependency tree will be identical every time. Secondly you might want to allow non-breaking changes (based on [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)) of your direct dependencies which gives you even less control of nested dependencies plus you again can't guarantee that your direct dependencies won't at some point break semantic versioning rules themselves.

The solution to all this is the `package-lock.json` file which as described above locks in the versions of the full dependency tree. This allows you to guarantee your dependency tree for other developers or for releases whilst still allowing testing of new dependency versions (direct or indirect) using your standard `package.json`.

NB. The previous [`npm-shrinkwrap.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/npm-shrinkwrap-json) did pretty much the same thing but the lock file renames it so that it's function is clearer. If there's already a shrink wrap file in the project then this will be used instead of any lock file.

### Edit 2023

Since NPM v8.3.0 (2021-12-09), `package.json` has a property `overrides` which might help you not to touch `package-lock.json` file.

> To make sure the package foo is always installed as version 1.0.0 no
> matter what version your dependencies rely on:

```json
{
  "overrides": {
    "foo": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: If having an exact version of dependencies is so sought after, why not enforce specifying the exact version in package.json and forgoe a package-lock.json file?

Comment: @jrahhali - have amended my answer based on your question.

Comment: How gets this dependency tree from pacakge.json.lock applied for other developers? Automatically?

Comment: Please note that this answer **is no longer correct**! The `package-lock.json` file is being updated **every single time you call npm install** since NPM 5.1. (change in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866, example in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979)
It therefore can **no longer be used to set the same versions for all developers**, unless you specify exact versions like `1.2.3` instead of `1.2.*` in your `package.json` file.

Comment: @jrahhli - Your comment does not take into consideration the package.json of dependencies. You can use exact semver, but that doesn't mean your dependencies will!

Comment: but if all your dependencies and dependencies of dependencies etc also use exact versions in their own package.json, then it'd not be needed? i.e. don't most packages use exact versions?

Comment: @Avery235 lol Perhaps someday everyone will see the light; probably not though. :p

Comment: The link in the answer is broken. Also, what is the new behavior?

Comment: You should add a reference to `npm ci` as `npm install` will update the package-lock.json whereas ci uses its content. Only with `npm ci` will you get repeatable robust builds.

Comment: Interesting finding, for me: the modules in my dependency tree got node_modules/*modules* installed when I did an npm uninstall in one module. The installed node_module/*modules* didn't match the current dependencies of the other modules. Seems that the npm uninstall caused npm to process package.lock and bring the dependency tree to that state, even though it wasn't the state of the other modules as defined in their package.json files. Didn't hurt output though.

Comment: @Matt I have a package in package.json file:
`
"dependencies": {
    "abcd": "^1.0.66",
}
`
And this package  is locked in package-lock.json file:
```
 "abcd": {
      "version": "1.0.66",
}
```
When I execute `npm install` then a new package gets installed of version `1.0.71`.
This is happening because of the caret sign and due to the version of npm which is `5.5.1.`.

Comment: @NN796 so you're saying that the package-lock file can't lock the dependency tree?

Comment: unfortunate naming decision, *lock* creates an assumption of os file description lock file. shuda called it package-tree, package-versions...

Comment: I want to know how npm check if a package's has become vulnerable in application. Even when we are using same version of node and that package like before.

Comment: Is it ok if I deleted the integrity line in package-lock.json ? I deleted from some stylesheet and the website became surprisingly faster.

Comment: My file is 20000 lines long. How on earth does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: How we can have semantic versioning when package-lock.json is committed and every developer has the same dependencies ? Does it mean, you still need to update npm package despite provided semantic versioning ?

Comment: @JohnIdlewood You still need to run `npm install`, if a new version is available, and allowed in your package.json, it will update your package-lock.json, which you should then commit.

Answer (score 100):

It's an very important improvement for npm: **guarantee exact same version of every package**.

How to make sure your project built with same packages in different environments in a different time? Let's say, you may use `^1.2.3` in your `package.json`, or some of your dependencies are using that way, but how can you ensure each time `npm install` will pick up same version in your dev machine and in the build server? **package-lock.json** will ensure that.

[`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) will re-generate the lock file.
When on build server or deployment server, do [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html)
(which will read from the lock file, and install the whole package tree)

Comment: Note that this is kinda outdated now. In 5.1.0 onward, "npm install" does not read from the `package-lock.json` file at all. It just installs from `package.json` like it used to. To make use of the `package-lock.json` file, you have to use the new "npm ci" command, which will install the exact versions listed in `package-lock.json` instead of the version-ranges given in `package.json`.

Comment: I'm afraid Venryx is incorrect.

`npm install` **does** read from `package-lock.json`. To reproduce, do the following.

using this package.json, run `npm install`
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "7.2.2"
  }
}

Now copy/paste `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to a new directory.

Change `package.json` to: "sinon": "^7.2.2"  

run `npm install`. npm reads from package-lock.json and installs 7.2.2 instead of 7.3.0. Without package-lock.json, 7.3.0 would be installed.

Comment: And not only that, but if you want to do something like add the caret ^ to `package-lock.json`, the only reasonable way to do that is to delete `package-lock.json` and regenerate it using `npm install`. (You don't want to manually edit `package-lock.json`). Changing the value of the "version" property (near the top) of `package.json` will change the same in `package-lock.json` on `npm install`, but adding a caret to a dependency will not do the same to `package-lock.json`.

Comment: @zumafra to me is not clear about the metadata like project name, licence etc, that are both in package.json and the package-lock.json one. Would of course those be have modified manually. Also is not clear based on what would be generated the package-lock.json from npm install

Comment: Think of `package.json` as something that you can manually modify, and `package-lock.json` as something that you never manually touch. You always version control BOTH files - especially `package-lock.json`. Open both files, manually edit the project name in `package.json`, run `npm install` and watch how the project name changes in `package-lock.json`. `license` doesn't seem to be recorded in `package-lock.json`.

Comment: `package.json` is basically a human-readable record of what software your project depends on. `package-lock.json` is a machine-generated record of the EXACT VERSIONS of the software dependencies YOU used (and listed in `package.json`) when you worked on your project. When you give me `package.json` ONLY and I run `npm install` two weeks later, I will have slightly different software dependencies installed on my machine. When you give me `package.json` AND `package-lock.json` and I run `npm install` two weeks later, I will have EXACTLY THE SAME software dependencies installed as you did.

Comment: @zumafra package-lock.json file will be use when doing `npm ci`, `npm install` will just use package.json, even though the lock file is provided

Comment: @Xin I have a package in package.json file:
"dependencies": {
    "abcd": "^1.0.66",
}

And this package  is locked in package-lock.json file:
 "abcd": {
      "version": "1.0.66",
}
. 
When I execute `npm install` then a package gets installed with new version of `1.0.71`.
This is happening because of the caret sign or due to the version of npm which is `5.5.1.` or both? Please confirm.

My understanding is `npm install` should pick the locked version `1.0.66` rather than `1.0.71`.

Comment: @NN796 i calrify it again in it. please refer, in summary, it -regenerate new lock file

Comment: @Xin Thank you. So the lock file gets updated due to the caret sign and the version of the npm which is 5.4.1 right?

Comment: @NN796 lock file gets updated just because of `npm install` cause each time execuate, it generates fresh one, and yes if > or ^, it will pickup new ones (be careful, including its sub dependencies)

Comment: @Xin can you please provide some suggestions on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019398/why-does-npm-install-git-repo-url-rewrite-package-lock-json

Comment: I helped that @NN796

Comment: As of NPM 6.14.8, none of the answers here seem accurate. I see range operators produced by NPM in the package-lock. `npm install bunyan --save-exact`  this yields a package-lock with this bunyan dependency, note the range operators in requires: `"bunyan": {
      "version": "1.8.14",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bunyan/-/bunyan-1.8.14.tgz",
      "integrity": "<trimmed to fit in comments>",
      "requires": {
        "dtrace-provider": "~0.8",
        "moment": "^2.19.3",
        "mv": "~2",
        "safe-json-stringify": "~1"
      }
    }`

Comment: Is it ok if I deleted the integrity line in package-lock.json ? I deleted from some stylesheet and the website became surprisingly faster.

Answer (score 48):

`package-lock.json` is written to when a numerical value in a property such as the "version" property, or a dependency property is changed in `package.json`.

If these numerical values in `package.json` and `package-lock.json` match, `package-lock.json` is read from.

If these numerical values in `package.json` and `package-lock.json` do not match, `package-lock.json` is written to with those new values, and new modifiers such as the caret and tilde if they are present. But it is the numeral that is triggering the change to `package-lock.json`.

To see what I mean, do the following. Using `package.json` without `package-lock.json`, run `npm install` with:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "7.2.2"
  }
}
```

`package-lock.json` will now have:

```
"sinon": {
  "version": "7.2.2",
```

Now copy/paste both files to a new directory. Change `package.json` to (only adding caret):

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "^7.2.2"
  }
}
```

run `npm install`. If there were no `package-lock.json` file, sinon@7.3.0 would be installed. `npm install` is **reading from** `package-lock.json` and installing 7.2.2.

Now change `package.json` to:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

run `npm install`. `package-lock.json` has been **written to**, and will now show:

```
"sinon": {
  "version": "^7.3.0",
```

Answer (score 18):

One important thing to mention as well is the security improvement that comes with the package-lock file. Since it keeps all the hashes of the packages if someone would tamper with the public npm registry and change the source code of a package without even changing the version of the package itself it would be detected by the package-lock file.

Answer (score 3):

This file is automatically created and used by npm to keep track of your package installations
and to better manage the state and history of your project’s dependencies. You
shouldn’t alter the contents of this file.

Comment: so what happens if I get a conflict with this file?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of `package-lock.json` file is to keep track of the exact version of every package that is installed so that a product is 100% reproducible in the same way even if packages are updated by their maintainers.

This solves a very specific problem that `package.json`left unsolved. In package.json you can set which versions you want to upgrade to (patch or minor), using the [semver notation](https://semver.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`package-lock.json`: It contains the exact version details that is currently installed for your Application.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This question has already been answered. You have to verify if the question has marked as answered seeing if any of the answers has a green ckeck in front of it.

Comment: @Néstor Don't get it wrong. One can answer to already answered question given that the answer is **new** and useful. (although it's not the case in this answer).

Comment: The answer you provided has already been given! Consider improving the quality of the information to make this a valuable answer!

Answer (score -2):

`package.json` file contains the main names of packages & libraries which you installed and you can edit it, but `package-lock.json` contains the details of each package and the link of repository of each package (consider it as the details of the packages which came from `package.json`).

*Reference*: [`package-lock`](https://web-brackets.com/discussion/69/what-is-the-use-of-package-lock-json-file)