# Do I need both package-lock.json and package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

After updating my NPM to the latest version (from 3.X to 5.2.0) and running `npm install` on an existing project, I get an auto-created `package-lock.json` file.

I can tell `package-lock.json` gives me an exact dependency tree as opposed to `package.json`.

From that info alone, it seems like `package.json` is redundant and not needed anymore.

Are both of them necessary for NPM to work?

Is it safe or possible to use only the `package-lock.json` file?

The docs on package-lock.json ([doc1](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json), [doc2](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks)) doesn't mention anything about that.

**Edit**:

After some more thinking about it, I came to the conclusion that if someone wants to use your project with an older version of NPM (before 5.x) it would still install all of the dependencies, but with less accurate versions (patch versions)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/package-lock-json-role)

Comment: @Omri unless you do it the java way and tool versions are determined by your project.  ie. if I go back 1 year in my repo, it uses an older version of gradle so I never worry about that.

Comment: Most people do not do what I recommend which is why npm probably had to keep both where in java, gradle wrapper is setup to do exactly that so they can move from one file to the other and have no duplication for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 268):

Do you need both `package-lock.json` and `package.json`? **No**.

Do you need the `package.json`? **Yes**.

Can you have a project with only the `package-lock.json`? **No**.

The `package.json` is used for more than dependencies - like defining project properties, description, author & license information, scripts, etc. The `package-lock.json` is solely used to lock dependencies to a specific version number.

Comment: instead of **npm install** use **npm ci** to install dependencies according to `package-lock.js`
- refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci

Answer (score 97):

`package-lock.json`: records the exact version of each installed package which allows you to re-install them. Future installs will be able to build an identical dependency tree.

`package.json`: records the minimum version you app needs. If you update the versions of a particular package, the change is not going to be reflected here.

Comment: If the above is true, and `package.json` records the minimum version needed by the app and package-lock.json records the exact version of each installed package, then I'm having a strange situation where a module is set at version 0.112.1 in package.json and 0.110.0 in package-lock.json...

Answer (score 13):

If your question is if lock file should be committed to your source control - it should. It will be ignored under certain circumstance.

I found it bloating pull requests and commit history, so if you see it change, do a separate commit for it.

Comment: No, I wasn't asking about commits to source control. Just if NPM needs both of them **at the same time** to work. `package-lock.json` seems like a more verbose version of `package.json`, so is it safe or possible to use only the lock file.

Comment: I see, I've left package.json in my projects, mainly to have a place for npm scripts.

Comment: There is now a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46164194) on whether to put `package-lock.json` under version control.