# What is the point of putting npm's "package-lock.json" under version control?

Tags: npm, version-control, package.json, package-lock.json

What is the point of putting npm's `package-lock.json` under version control? In my experience having this file source controlled has caused more trouble and confusion than efficiency gains.

Having `package-lock.json` under source control makes for a **major headache** every time a developer who added/removed/modified any node modules needs to **resolve conflicts** between branches. Especially working on a complex/large apps where the package-lock.json can be tens of thousands of lines long. Even just blowing away node_modules and running a fresh `npm install` can generate drastic changes in the package-lock.

There are several other SO questions about the package-lock:

- [Do I commit the package-lock.json file created by npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)
- [Npm - package-lock.json role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/package-lock-json-role)
- [Why does npm install rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)

And a GitHub issue with a ton of conversation about package-lock:

- [package-lock.json file not updated after package.json file is changed](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866)

Which makes me think there is still widespread uncertainty that needs cleared up.

According to the docs

> `package-lock.json` is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json.

So **why would you ever want to put an automatically generated file under source control?**

The above GitHub issue details how some people, in response to confusion with the package-lock.json, change their `npm install` script to `rm -f package-lock.json && npm install`, which also does not feel correct.

It seems like `package-lock.json` is striving to be the source of truth for the exact version of node module dependencies, but isn't that exactly what the package.json does? When does the excruciating pain of resolving merge conflicts in this file start to pay off?

Comment: Your team should have agreed to solely follow the "current working" module versions in your package-lock.json every time there's a code change unless you all agree that a current module needs to be upgraded. This way, package-lock.json let everyone know which module version is required and "currently working" with your application.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience, **it does not make sense to put `package-lock.json` under version control**. It makes managing large merge/rebases a nightmare. However, there are instances where the **package-lock can be very useful**.

Recently (2017/10/10) moment.js introduced [breaking changes in a minor version update](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4216). Meaning **if one was to ship with no package-lock.json**, and had something like this in their package.json:

`"moment": "^2.12.0"`

Some breaking changes introduced in version 2.19.0 would silently infiltrate your code with almost no trace.

This is why after *cutting a branch to serve as a release candidate* it is crucial to:

- remove package-lock.json from .gitignore
- run `npm install` to generate a package-lock.json
- test, qa, deploy with this package-lock

This assures your npm module versions will remain locked down on the same versions that were tested.

Comment: Locking down versions, isn't that what `npm shrinkwrap` is for?

Comment: Isn't doing a breaking change in a minor version update also a big no-no?

Comment: True, but this is just a gentleman's agreement. Doesn't always hold true in the real world

Comment: Downvoting. Lockfiles should always be in version control, or else you can’t have repeatable builds.

Comment: I agree, lockfiles should be submitted to version control. However after running `npx create-react-app` I am now staring down a `package-lock.json` with 38k lines. That is 38 **thousand** lines and more than 1kb in size. This is simply way too large to version control.

Comment: @AttilaViniczai Yes, the format can be awkward, but why do you think there’s such a thing as “too large to version control”? You don’t need to do much with that file manually, but it has to be available in the repo in order to manage your dependencies properly.

Comment: "more than 1kb in size" 

Answer (score 6):

IMO `package-lock.json` (or `yarn-lock.json`) should *always* be committed to source control. Merge/rebase conflicts aside (which are largely mitigated by `yarn` BTW - you can `yarn install` mid-rebase to resolve issues automatically), it is the best guarantee you have that the code at that commit will build and run correctly after a fresh checkout and install.

Answer (score 5):

Create a .gitattributes entry:

```
# common settings that generally should always be used with your language specific settings

# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

#
# The above will handle all files NOT found below
#

#*.svg text
*.lock binary
```

Then when you merge you will only have to choose a version vs code merges. Thought you might run into package conflicts this way.

We have mitigated that by checking versions in the build process.

Comment: The `*.lock` in the last line of  the .gitattributes shown does not seem to make sense as the this is about `package-lock.json`. Did you mean `package-lock.json binary` instead?

Comment: I really like this answer as a general concept, but like @Adrian, I think the use of *.lock binary isn't exactly what you might want. After reading https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes, I am going to try using *lock.json -diff in my .gitattributes file to see if that works.


Additionally, the line with * text=auto is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a long time ago. Since then, some things have changed, now we have a `npm ci` (clean install) command. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155), I explain the value of the `package-lock.json` for having reproducible environments with the `npm ci` vs `npm install`.