# NPM5, What is the difference of package-lock.json with package.json?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, package.json, package-lock.json

After updating NPM to version 5, I found `package-lock.json` file with package.json.

What is the difference between this two files?

What are the advantages of `package-lock.json`?

Answer (score 16):

A package.json file: lists the packages that your project depends on. allows you to specify the versions of a package that your project can use using semantic versioning rules.

According to the npm docs,

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json . It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.
>
> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and serves various purposes:
>
> - Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies.
> - Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
> - To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source control diffs.

Basically package-lock.json is used to optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

Before npm 5.x.x, package.json was the source of truth for a project. What lived in package.json was law. npm users liked this model and grew very accustomed to maintaining their package file. However, when package-lock was first introduced, it acted contrary to how many people expected it to. Given a pre-existing package and package-lock, a change to the package.json (what many users considered the source of truth) was not reflected in the package-lock.

Example: Package A, version 1.0.0 is in the package and package-lock. In package.json, A is manually edited to version 1.1.0. If a user who considers package.json to be the source of truth runs `npm install`, they would expect version 1.1.0 to be installed. However, version 1.0.0 is installed, despite the fact that v1.1.0 is listed is the package.json.

Example: A module does not exist in the package-lock, but it does exist in the package.json. As a user who looks to package.json as the source of truth, I would expect for my module to be installed. However since the module is not present in package-lock, it isn’t installed, and my code fails because it cannot find the module.

Read more about package-lock.json in the [Official npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)!

Comment: This is by far the easiest explanation yet no votes!

Comment: @Debadatta that's because the question had already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052520/do-i-need-both-package-lock-json-and-package-json)

Comment: Then why to keep package.json track the dependencies at all?

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` records only your direct dependencies and their versions.

`package-lock.json` records not only your direct dependencies and exact versions, but also those of all dependencies of your dependencies - the entire dependency tree, in other words, with exact versions.

---

It's the fact that `package-lock.json` records the exact versions of *all* dependencies of a project, including sub-dependencies, that ensures that builds will be identical each time. (This is why `npm ci` bases its build on `package-lock.json`, not `package.json`.)

Builds based on `package.json` (as with `npm i`) cannot guarantee that all sub-dependencies are the exact same versions each build (e.g., if the subdependency of one of your dependencies releases an update, but the version of your direct dependency doesn't change), even if exact version numbers for *direct dependencies* are specified in the `package.json`.