# Whats difference between package-lock.json and package.json, when is package.json generated?

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

When is package.json generated?
How it maintain consistency in various environments ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the role of the package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM5, What is the difference of package-lock.json with package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456236/npm5-what-is-the-difference-of-package-lock-json-with-package-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

package-lock.json: records the exact version of each installed package which allows you to re-install them. Future installs will be able to build an identical dependency tree.

package.json: records the minimum version you app needs. If you update the versions of a particular package, the change is not going to be reflected here.

Checkout this thread : [Do I need both package-lock.json and package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052520/do-i-need-both-package-lock-json-and-package-json)

Comment: copy in here, you can comment it: https://delegatecall.com/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-packagejson-and-packagelockjson-2bd0e4e1-a65f-4d78-b8d8-b51905a37adb