# What is package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, nconf

I'm using WebStorm and making with node.js

I installed npm module like `nconf` and package-lock.json has made.

I expected package.json would've been made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["package-lock.json" role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/package-lock-json-role)

Answer (score 8):

Describe the dependency tree in a given moment, so with this description all the dependencies can be created again exactly the same way it was, this ensures the expected behavior from the dependencies.

In the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) you can read:

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.
>
> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and serves various purposes:
>
> Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies.
>
> Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
>
> To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source control diffs.
>
> And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

Package-lock.json file contains the dependencies listed in your package.json file and the specific version of the dependency that should be installed

Comment: Isn't that what `package.json` does?