# How will I get all compatible package version while updating node version 8 to 10?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-check-updates

I want to update node version from 8 to 10.

So have to update all npm packages which is compatible with node 10.
I can not run `npm update` because it will update all packages to lattes version which might be not compatible with node 10.

One way to check every package version compatibility in their documentation and use that version into my `package.json` file.

`npm-check-updates` only talk about current version and latest version but not talk about compatible version.

I am looking smart way to do this.

Kindly suggest me something better solution.
I will appreciate all responses.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. But npm will notify you if a package is not compatible with current node version as far as I know.

Comment: if npm know, which version is compatible with node version then there must be a way to do.

Comment: As far as I know, there seems to be nothing like that. A similar question was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571617/check-npm-packages-compatibility-with-node-latest-version

Please post if you find any solution.