# packages.json: suppress looking for new versions

Tags: npm, packages.json

Is there any way we can suppress not to look for new versions during npm install. I know we can remove it from packages.json but doing the same thing in every dependent packages can quite become a challenge. The current problem i have is our company doesn't allow us to pull from public domain unless they are accepted and added to our private repository. Every time we add all the packages and after couple of days if we run npm install it will fail since a new minor or major version is released and we don't have it in our repository.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/package-lock-json-role

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Just recently Npm release `npm ci` command especially for such purposes. It strictly follows the `package-lock.json` file

I think starting with npm5 you have a lock file which solves that problem. In addition you could try `npm shrinkwrap` command, which is a bit older approach, it creates the shrinkwrap.json file with exact version of packages and next time npm will use only this versions.

Comment: Thank You So Much!...I will try this option and feel like this will solve my issue.