# Install via npm all dependencies in package.json from a project A to a project B?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

I am wondering if there is a native way of install all dependencies listed in package.json from a Project A to a Project B except the way of use Python virtual env or another more "heavy" solution as use Docker image( but I think this would be overkilling).

Comment: How about installing the package? But if you only want to merge them... I don’t think so :/

Comment: I realized that this isn't quite possible due the fact that package.json does have also metadata like project name, licenze etc. This will collide, so even a copy and past of the dependencies would be possible. On top of that to have all the tree of dependencies it should also be copied package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

yes in the terminal in the project simply type `npm i` and it will look for a package.json if it finds one it will download all the packages in it, if it doesnt find one it will ask you to create on

Comment: Are in this way  going to install them globally?Should ti work doing npm i --save-dev?

Comment: So should I also include package-lock.json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: all you need is the package.json, just copy and paste it wherever you need it