# Can't build VueJS webpack based project after removing node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I recently had some issue with the web project on which I'm working and tried to remove `node_modules` folder. But after removing and reinstalling it from a scratch, I can't build a project at all, not for development neither in production. When I run `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
macbook:coolapp-web-fe.v2 anatolyt$ PORT=8087 npm run dev

> coolapp@2.0.45 dev /Users/anatolyt/work/coolapp-web-fe.v2
> webpack-dev-server --inline --watch --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 19% building modules 82/115 modules 33 active ...partials/pages-carcass/flex-block.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as 65% building modules 506/548 modules 42 active .../partials/table/colorBarVariables.vue^C^C^C
macbook:coolapp-web-fe.v2 anatolyt$ PORT=8087 npm run dev

> coolapp@2.0.45 dev /Users/anatolyt/work/coolapp-web-fe.v2
> webpack-dev-server --inline --watch --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 19% building modules 82/115 modules 33 active ...src/components/partials/card-wrap.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as 63% building modules 499/564 modules 65 active ...2/node_modules/moment/locale/zh-hk.js^C^C^C
macbook:coolapp-web-fe.v2 anatolyt$ PORT=8087 npm run dev

> coolapp@2.0.45 dev /Users/anatolyt/work/coolapp-web-fe.v2
> webpack-dev-server --inline --watch --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 19% building modules 82/115 modules 33 active ...rc/components/partials/form-group.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as 65% building modules 986/1057 modules 71 active ...headerGroup/headerGroupWrapperComp.js
```

When I build a project for the development (building Docker's image) by running the following code:

```
FROM node:8-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
RUN npm i --production
```

On last line `RUN npm i --production` I get the following error:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/core-js-967e32e1/client/library.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/vue-form-wizard-25ea249a/src/components/WizardButton.vue'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/vue-form-wizard-25ea249a/src/components/WizardStep.vue'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/ag-grid-vue-df63d144/gulpfile.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/ag-grid-vue-df63d144/LICENSE.txt'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/ag-grid-vue-df63d144/main.js'
```

I understand that it's too broad error and the various issues can cause to it, but at least some tips how can I debug this issue would be helpful.
I tried to remove `packaga-lock.json` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason why Docker's image wasn't building with the following error:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/vue-form-wizard-25ea249a/src/components/WizardStep.vue'
```

We have a private `npm` module which requires that username and password will be specified in `.npmrc` file. I forget to include this file in Docker image.

When I changed the following line:

```
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
```

to

```
COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
```

Everything began to work.

The only issue which remained, if I remove a `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` from the scratch `npm run dev` command hangs later. When I restore a `package-lock.json` older version from a git, it works fine. It's definitely packet conflicts, but I can't understand which one right now.

**UPDATE** Regarding `package-lock.json` issue. It's created at the point when `npm install` was run fist time and it keeps dependencies relevant at that point of time, [read here what does it do for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json). Since then some dependencies have been changed and this caused to breaking changes. You can compare `package-lock.json` generated then and now, see the differences in versions and try to catch one which breaks the building. Another option is to use this fork of `npm` [npm install --time-machine (ignore packages released after a given date)](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12994) and try to run `npm install` at different point of time to look when the issue begins. I haven't used it yet, but hopefully will use it and will update my answer here.

Comment: Delete your lock files, and remove the package-lock.json from your command lines above. The run npm install. Does it throw the same errors?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work when with a fresh install. I'm going possibly to use this `npm fork` https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/12995