# vulnerability audit on npm install

Tags: node.js

I'm making a website with a node express backend, which serves a react app from the public directory. Everything was working fine on my computer, I put all of this on an AWS server, ran npm install for my server, and for my app in the public directory, that's where I got that message:

```
/public$ npm audit fix

up to date, audited 1960 packages in 5s

# npm audit report

public  *
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1000
Path Traversal - https://npmjs.com/advisories/571
Cross-Site Scripting - https://npmjs.com/advisories/609
fix available via `npm audit fix`


1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

Everything was fine on my computer, I tried starting over again, emptying the node_modules directory then reinstall, but same thing again. I guess I must have not copied/deleted some files but I have no idea where to start, and I don't get what's the "public *" is that a module? You're welcome if you have some ideas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "npm audit fix" exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416717/what-does-npm-audit-fix-exactly-do)

Comment: I am experiencing this issue and it makes absolutely no sense. npm audit flags up this vulnerability if I add *any* dependency in my package.json. Literally anything. When I install exactly the same packages on a different environment, there is no problem - npm audit shows 0 vulnerabilities. This issue is absolutely contingent on the install environment. It's nothing to do with a vulnerable local package being brought in either, as it persists even when forcing pulls from the remote npm repo. A real head-scratcher.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you run `npm install`, another command, called `npm audit` is also executed. It's a tool to check if your project's dependencies have some known vulnerabilities.

It has nothing to do with your environment, local or AWS, it's all about dependencies.

[Auditing package dependencies for security vulnerabilities](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)

The `npm audit --fix` can automatically fix vulnerabilities, however, documentation says that in some cases manual intervention might be required.

[npm audit command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-audit)

You need to closely look at the output of the command, maybe, if interested, read about the vulnerability and fix it.