# Every time I try to make React app it is looking for funding & have some vulnerabilities. & then get stuck

Tags: node.js, reactjs

`
PS C:\Users\Avesh\Documents\web development practice\React JS> npx create-react-app new-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Avesh\Documents\web development practice\React JS\new-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

added 1969 packages, and audited 1970 packages in 2m

137 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

80 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run: npm audit fixstrong text

Run npm audit for details.
`

Comment: Please add clarity to your question rather than simply posting an error message

Comment: `npx` seems to be working fine. Maybe see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58972251/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65631237/3001761.

Comment: I don't see a problem here

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You see that information - so what? Per the links above this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: run `npm fund` and start sending money to developers

Comment: no it isn't working even if I use npm fund or npm cache-clear --f or npm create -g react-app my-app help me to make a basic react app

Comment: The requests for funding, and audit report of possible vulnerabilities of packages, aren't blocking errors, they're just warnings. "it isn't working" - what isn't working? Please be specific about your problems and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the solution on someone blog. [Click here to see the solution in the blog](https://dev.to/tiwariaditya/how-to-fix-npm-create-react-app-stuck-at-found-0-vulnerabilities-323k)

Fix 1 (Easy One)-
I don't know why but this problem is observed with 12.16.2-x64.msi node version. If you installed x64 version then you just need to uninstall this version and install x32 bit version. This fix should solve your problem.

Fix 2-
If you don't want to reinstall node and continue with the current version then this fix would work.

Open a new cmd window and run resmon command. This command opens resource monitor and you would see something like this -
Alt Text

Once you could see resource monitor. You need to start looking for cmd.exe processes (because there would be more than one cmd.exe based on how many windows you have got open) which are suspended. You could see if a process is suspended by right-clicking on it.Alt Text
If you find any cmd.exe suspended resume it. Your cmd process would also get resumed. There might be a case where cmd again stops, you just follow the above steps again.
The only problem with this is you might need to follow these steps 1 or 2 times more when using npx create-react-app before the error goes away.

Answer (score -1):

Don't type in npx or npm ,I have dealt with it several times. Just type in create react app and then the name...