# i ve some problem with npx create react app can sbd show me how to fix it plss

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\transparent login form> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\transparent login form\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

added 1918 packages, and audited 1919 packages in 2m

145 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

22 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 13 high)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: What's the actual issue? I don't see any error messages, only warnings, and most you can't fix, because they're vulnerabilities in packages

Comment: Conaider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on someone blog. [Click here to see the solution in the blog](https://dev.to/tiwariaditya/how-to-fix-npm-create-react-app-stuck-at-found-0-vulnerabilities-323k)

Fix 1 (Easy One)- I don't know why but this problem is observed with 12.16.2-x64.msi node version. If you installed x64 version then you just need to uninstall this version and install x32 bit version. This fix should solve your problem.

Fix 2- If you don't want to reinstall node and continue with the current version then this fix would work.

Open a new cmd window and run resmon command. This command opens resource monitor and you would see something like this - Alt Text

Once you could see resource monitor. You need to start looking for cmd.exe processes (because there would be more than one cmd.exe based on how many windows you have got open) which are suspended. You could see if a process is suspended by right-clicking on it.Alt Text If you find any cmd.exe suspended resume it. Your cmd process would also get resumed. There might be a case where cmd again stops, you just follow the above steps again. The only problem with this is you might need to follow these steps 1 or 2 times more when using npx create-react-app before the error goes away.

This solution is copied from [Every time I try to make React app it is looking for funding & have some vulnerabilities. & then get stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640895/every-time-i-try-to-make-react-app-it-is-looking-for-funding-have-some-vulnera/67675650#67675650)