# `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to ask you, when I install some package terminal show me warning:

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I always fix this warning with `npm audit fix` , but why is it still showing me this msg?
Should I reinstall something, or should I ignore it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "npm audit fix" exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416717/what-does-npm-audit-fix-exactly-do)

Comment: It's probably because some fixes would require breaking change, and they aren't applied with straight `npm audit fix`