# React security vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've been testing working with react & node js but as I'm still very new, I'm unsure of how to resolve the errors I'm receiving below.

I've already tried addressing them with **npm audit fix** and **npm audit fix --force** to no avail.

I also tried uninstalling **request** and the same errors pop..

Thank you!
(in root)
request  *
Severity: moderate
Server-Side Request Forgery in Request - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p8p7-x288-28g6
No fix available
node_modules/request
fuel-auth  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of request
node_modules/fuel-auth
fuel-rest  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of fuel-auth
Depends on vulnerable versions of request
node_modules/fuel-rest

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

(in client)
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/nth-check
css-select  <=3.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/css-select
svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/svgo
@svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
@svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
node_modules/@svgr/webpack
react-scripts  >=2.1.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
uninstalling packages

Comment: I got the errors in the client dir to resolve by using npm update instead of npm install name@latest.

Comment: resolved the second set of errors by installing request globally

Answer (score 0):

`npm audit` is not a useful tool for determining real vulnerabilities in your code. The TL;DR is that it will display "high severity" issues that do not actually exist in your application, most of the time.

See: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/ and [What does "npm audit fix" exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416717/what-does-npm-audit-fix-exactly-do)

Comment: Got it, thanks for mentioning this. It keeps giving me the same errors every now & then related to svgo and css-select, but this seems to be a recurring theme.