# To what end are we maintaining package-lock.json files that are free of security vulnerabilities? Why not just delete them or let them go stale?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependabot

`package-lock.json` stores a set of exact versions for all the dependencies and transitive dependencies that got installed when someone last ran `npm update`. You are encouraged to commit `package-lock.json` back to your repo.

The only real consumer of `package-lock.json` that I can find is `npm ci`, which reproduces the state defined in `package-lock.json` exactly so that you can be sure you're running CI on the same dependencies you had on the dev machine that last wrote `package-lock.json`.

The other thing `package-lock.json` seems to be used for is producing reams and reams of security warnings. I've got Github's Dependabot PR-ing changes to my committed `package-lock.json` files, and complaining that my `package-lock.json` is where it "found" other vulnerabilities that it can't automatically fix for me. I suspect these unfixable issues are problems in either my or a dependency's `package.json`, caused by a maximum version requirement that excludes the fixed version of the offending module, but that's not what Dependabot says:

[image: Dependabot saying I have a problem with package-lock.json that it can't fix]

If `package-lock.json` is only used by `npm ci`, how can a reference to an outdated and vulnerable version of a package there create a vulnerability anywhere except in my CI system? Won't anyone who actually installs the package use `package.json` to resolve dependencies and hence get fixes for all the vulnerabilities automatically as they are made available (unless I myself have an offending maximum version limit)? Are these PRs to my repo really just suggestions that me and all my users/collaborators run `npm update` on our machines? If so, what possessed the Dependabot authors to do this via pull request?

If I remove `package-lock.json` from source control, will that properly resolve `package-lock.json`-indiced vulnerabilities (because the file no longer exists to trick someone into installing old vulnerable versions of my dependencies)? Or will it just render the vulnerability scanners unable to scan my repo (i.e. do they rely on `package-lock.json` instead of resolving dependencies themselves from `package.json`) and make me not know when I need to `npm update`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the role of the package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json)

Comment: Not quite. It gives some insight into how `package-lock.json` was supposed to be used for syncing up developers' machines (which now no longer happens by default with `npm install`), how it is used for CI, and how you can use it to go back in time. It mentions it being used for packaging releases with all modules included, so I suppose if you release like that instead of just on NPM the vulnerability scanners can help you. But it doesn't give insight into why upping module versions is important enough for all projects to merit a Github-integrated bot.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this question as well. GitHub security bots keep bumping versions in package-lock.json while package.json remains at the same version and says vulnerabilities are gone. How does this even work?