# which files are created/modified when I do npm install in an angular project? (in my case angular 8)

Tags: angular, npm, angular8

which files are created/modified when I do npm install in an angular project? (in my case angular 8)
do package.lock.json also along with node modules needs to be deleted when Ι update something in package.json , will npm install create package.lock.json on it's own like node modules.
Τhanks.

Comment: Kindly go through the beginner's guide of asking a question on this stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .It is always helpful for the others who are reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***package-lock.json*** is updated with every normal npm install to constantly reflect the packages that were used on the last build. To use exactly the versions pinned in **package-lock.json** , one needs to use the command

> npm ci

Try refering to this link [What is the role of the package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json) for more detailed discussion regarding this. Try to search your doubts first you may find similar questions already answered.