# Cant install vite on laravel project which worked on another computer

Tags: laravel, npm, vite

I cannot npm install plugins, or use ones exisiting in the project, as it gives out errors of dependencies on versions I dont have installed.

Basically running npm i gives me this error:

```
ubulara@DESKTOP-B4JC6VG:~/aramis/project$ npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.16
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^2.9.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.1" from the root project
```

Trying to install the specific plugin-vue package gives me:

```
ubulara@DESKTOP-B4JC6VG:~/aramis/project$ npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.0.1
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.16
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^2.9.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"3.0.1" from the root project
```

And trying to install the specific vite version gives me:

```
ubulara@DESKTOP-B4JC6VG:~/aramis/project$ npm install vite@2.9.11
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.11
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"2.9.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.1" from the root project
```

I dont understand why dependencies would break changing computer, my npm is 9.5.1 and laravel framework is 9.30.1
Bypassing with "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" doesnt work either, as then it gives me these errors:

```
ubulara@DESKTOP-B4JC6VG:~/aramis/project$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

failed to load config from /home/ubulara/aramis/project/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: vite.createFilter is not a function
    at vuePlugin (/home/ubulara/aramis/project/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.cjs:2601:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubulara/aramis/project/vite.config.js:43:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/home/ubulara/aramis/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-689425f3.js:62006:20)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at loadConfigFromBundledFile (/home/ubulara/aramis/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-689425f3.js:62014:17)
    at loadConfigFromFile (/home/ubulara/aramis/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-689425f3.js:61933:32)
```

```
ubulara@DESKTOP-B4JC6VG:~/aramis/project$ npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! Found: vite@2.9.15
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^2.9.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^2.9.9" from laravel-vite-plugin@0.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin
npm ERR!     dev laravel-vite-plugin@"^0.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (vite-plugin-full-reload)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vite@3.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!     dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.1" from the root project
```

I'm actually going crazy over this issue, maybe I just dont understand how npm works at all? Been trying to fix this for almost two days now

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vite": "^2.9.11",
        "vue": "^3.2.37",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

I installed vite with "apt-get install vite", then removed it, could that have done something?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `package-lock.json` so you don't need to re-create the dependency tree. See [What is the role of the package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json)

Comment: Ok, maybe I should've added, that this repo already has the package-lock, and it works fine on another computer/other devs