# React - Folder Structure - Package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

We have the Package.json file which consist of the dependencies which are used in our source but why another file Package-lock.json is there which also consist of several versions of our dependencies list ?

is anyone available to clarify my ques >>>>>

ive tried to ask my senior and he says its for particular version, but im not satified with his answer because we already have the versions of dependencies at Package.json then why we need package-lock.json

Comment: Does [this question and it's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44297803/18057908) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

From ChatGPT:

The `package-lock.json` file in Node.js and npm projects serves an important purpose in ensuring consistent and reproducible builds. While the `package.json` file lists your project's dependencies, it doesn't always specify exact versions. The `package-lock.json` file, on the other hand, keeps track of the specific versions of each dependency that your project is using. Here's why both files are important:

1. **Exact Dependency Versions**:

   The `package.json` file specifies your project's dependencies, including the minimum and maximum versions allowed. However, it doesn't guarantee that the exact same versions will be used by all developers or in different environments. This can lead to unexpected issues due to differences in dependency versions.
2. **Reproducibility**:

   The `package-lock.json` file is generated by npm to lock down the exact versions of each dependency used in your project. It includes all the direct and transitive dependencies with their specific versions. This ensures that every developer and every environment uses the same versions, making your builds reproducible.
3. **Security and Stability**:

   Using specific versions of dependencies helps ensure the security and stability of your project. If a new version of a dependency introduces a critical security vulnerability or breaking changes, you want to be able to control when to update to that version. The `package-lock.json` file allows you to do that.
4. **Efficient Dependency Resolution**:

   The `package-lock.json` file speeds up dependency resolution. When you or another developer runs `npm install`, npm can use the `package-lock.json` to quickly determine the exact versions to download without consulting the npm registry, which can be time-consuming.

In summary, the `package-lock.json` file provides a mechanism to ensure consistent, reproducible, and controlled dependency management for your Node.js projects. While you can manage dependencies using the `package.json` file alone, the `package-lock.json` file is an important tool for maintaining a stable and secure project, particularly in larger and collaborative codebases. It's recommended to include the `package-lock.json` file in version control to share and maintain consistent dependency versions across your development team.