npm unable to resolve dependency tree untill deletion of node_modules
try to understand an error report of npm and fail to find the problem - surprisingly the deletion of the node_modules directory fixed it. We were in the process to update angular to 18+ and nx to 19+.
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.3.2
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"18.0.4" from the root project
  peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">= 15.0.0 < 18.0.0" from @nx/angular@18.3.4
  node_modules/@nx/angular
    @nx/angular@"19.3.0" from the root project
    @nx/angular@"18.3.4" from @nrwl/angular@18.3.4
    node_modules/@nrwl/angular
      @nrwl/angular@"18.3.4" from @nx/angular@18.3.4
  peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=15.0.0 <18.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@14.0.3
  node_modules/jest-preset-angular
    dev jest-preset-angular@"14.1.1" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"18.0.4" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@18.0.3
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
  peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.0.4
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
    dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"18.0.4" from the root project

How i understand the last part:

@angular-devkit/build-angular@18.0.4 found in package.json
package has peer dependency to @angular/compiler-cli@^18.0.0
failed to resolve @angular/compiler-cli@18.0.3 (which is also in package.json)

Why does it fail to resolve @angular/compiler-cli@18.0.3 when its clearly a valid version ?
How i understand the first part:

jest-preset-angular@14.1.1 found in package.json
version 14.0.3 of this package has peer dependency to @angular-devkit/build-angular@>=15.0.0 <18.0.0
(resolving errors based on wrong version range)

Why does npm use the old version of jest-preset-angular and nx/angular for resolving ? it seems like it ignore versions specified in the package.json and use the current installed.
(deleting nod_modules to fix an npm dependency problem seem like a bug in npm itself to me)
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.components": "8.1.3",
    "@abp/ng.core": "8.1.3",
    "@abp/ng.oauth": "8.1.3",
    "@abp/ng.theme.shared": "8.1.3",
    "@angular/animations": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "18.0.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "18.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "18.0.0",
    "@ngrx/operators": "18.0.0",
    "@nx/angular": "19.3.0",
    "@puschie286/golden-layout": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.12",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^17.0.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.1",
    "primeng-locale": "github:primefaces/primelocale",
    "primeng-sass-theme": "github:primefaces/primeng-sass-theme",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "ts-debounce": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.schematics": "^8.1.3",
    "@abp/nx.generators": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "18.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "18.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "18.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "18.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "18.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "18.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "18.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "18.0.3",
    "@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "18.0.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "18.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "18.0.0",
    "@nx-dotnet/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@nx/cypress": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/eslint": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/jest": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/js": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/plugin": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/web": "19.3.0",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.3.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "18.0.4",
    "@swc-node/register": "1.9.2",
    "@swc/core": "1.5.7",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^8.0.0-alpha.28",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "cypress": "13.8.1",
    "daisyui": "^4.6.3",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.15.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.9.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "14.1.1",
    "jsonc-eslint-parser": "^2.4.0",
    "nx": "19.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.4.3"
  }


@nx/angular@18.3.4 and jest-preset-angular@14.0.3 both specify that they need a @angular-devkit/build-angular that is >= 15.0.0 < 18.0.0.
Unfortunately, this range does not include any version of 18.x.x. The latest version matching that range is 17.3.8 according to the NPM semver calculator.
For @nx/angular it looks like this was fixed in https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/22509. For jest-preset-angular it was fixed in https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1410-2024-05-21.
It uses the old versions because you likely have a package-lock.json which is storing the transitive versions of these dependencies from a previous install. This is by design and best practice -- but it requires some extra work to manage in complex upgrade scenarios. Please see package-lock.json.
With the latest NPM, you need to do something like npm update --save @nx/angular jest-preset-angular.
And ensure the resulting changes to the package-lock.json and (possibly, this will only change if they were direct deps) package.json are committed. Make sure in CI that it fails the build if someone commits a change that should have caused a package-lock.json update, but it was not included. Practically that means in CI you use npm ci and never npm install.
And of course, never commit node_modules.

is there an option to ignore the installed versions and resolve with the package.json versions ? tried to delete/rename package-lock.json but same result

You shouldnt ever really delete package-lock.json as it means you have uncontrolled dependency tree change (security nightmare). You'll see people recommend it online, but that's because they didn't understand package locking. Sometimes you might not care though. DId you run the command specified in my answer? If you've got stale references in your package.jsons the tree would still be recreated incorrectly.

I can help more if you can post the package.jsons. But npm update --save does what you asked. But it wont magically break out of package.json semver versions. If you need that, you want npm outdated.

thanks npm update --save seems to do the trick - was unsure if it works without specifying the packages, because this would be very tedious when switching between commits.

So you don't ever want to run this day-to-day between branches/commits. This is an actual meaningful change to the dep tree and doing that would diverge from the versions at that time. When you switch branch/commit, you should just do "npm install". And that will install the correct versions from the locklfile. It sounds like possibly your CI is not enforcing proper lockfile management and its got out of sync along the way. Change to lockfile --> now running on a new dep tree compared to the the commit it was from.

Running it here is correct though, as you are actively trying to change the dep tree. You will then commit the resulting lock file. If you got into a situation where, with some given package-lock.,json and package.json, it was uninstallable -- its a sure sign someone has committed some dep change without the lockfile changes and CI didn't stop them which means you no longer have reproducable builds.

Also, make sure everyone is using desired (latest stable) version of NPM and CI also uses it. Enforce this through the engines property in package.json. Old versions of NPM are buggy and misalignment is another reason you can get into this position. Another problem is if someone added package-lock.json to gitignore (very bad!).

im a bit confused because npm update --save installed exactly the version specified in package.json but npm install upgraded some versions. Beside, an nx update (nx migrate latest) had cause this resolution fail, so it broke before the package-lock could be updated. But now i understand the different between install and update, so this should help me with future problems - thanks again

npm update --save is something you would run when wanting to update all deps (you do here) and commit the resulting changes. As a developer on day to day, you don't want to always "run on latest deps". You want to "run the same versions as everybody else, including transitive packages". package.json is not enough by itself to get reproduceable installs due to transitive depedency ranges. So npm install uses the lockfile. If you run npm install on a known branch with a proper committed lockfile, it should not result in any changes on git status. If it does, that's bad.

If you have branches/commits though with bad lockfiles, or out of sync lockfile to the package json, it would indeed change things. Like if an old branch doesn't even have a lockfile committed, then basically your in the wild west with non-perfectly bounded transitive dep versions. Hence you usually enforce this in CI by using npm ci.

This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json
